# Javascript append tags to selected area

Tags: javascript, onclick, textarea, append

I've got the following javascript, which allows me to append certain text to a textarea. However, this only appends to the end of the textarea.

If i have existing text in the textarea and then I click on a certain position in that area, when i click the button i would like the tag to appear where my cursor was placed.

any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
   Field.value += '[' + tag + ']' + '[/' + tag + ']';
}
</script> 

<form name="my_form"> 
    <textarea id="mytextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px;"></textarea><br /> 

    <input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="formatText ('B');" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Italic" onclick="formatText ('I');" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Underline" onclick="formatText ('U');" /> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concat all the parts

```
   Field.value =  before_txt + '[' + tag + ']' + selected_txt + '[/' + tag + ']' + after_txt;
```